# angular datepicker pick week

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to use angular datepicker for picking week instead of date.

I am not sure how I can achieve that, I know I can do that with bootstrap datepicker like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/IamMHussain/ozdrdbqf/1/).

How can I do same with `ngx-bootstrap` datepicker? When user picks a date I want to return and display start day of the week and end day of the week.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know if ngx-bootstrap `bsValueChange` is dispathed in a Daterangepicker when you select the first date, if true, the only is get the day of the week, calculate the two dates and close the daterangepicker

Comment: @Eliseo Any other angular datepicker which i can use?